# Do vs Dost, the difference

Tags: meaning, grammar, british-english, word-order, early-modern-english

"Thou coward knight, why wilt thou not do battle with me?" -*The Age of Chivalry, Chapter 16*

In this sentence, why is *do* not *dost*? Very commonly do I see the word *dost* be used in older text in place of *do* when using the 2nd person, but rarely do I see it as *do*. I can't find a grammatical explanation for this - or is it a choice of inconsistency by the author?- or perhaps a choice of fluidity over grammatical correctness?

Comment: Because it's an infinitive. Just like it's not _thou wilt art_ in Early Modern English or _you will are_ in Modern English, but _thou wilt be_ and _you will be_, respectively. _Wilt_ is the word you're looking to focus on here.

Comment: Which form of infinitive is it?

Comment: The infinitive does not inflect in modern English, so it only has one form.

Comment: @Bryan How do you mean which form? English has only one infinitive.

Comment: dost is the third person singular of the verb to DO. Here, the do is infinitive, it is not the third person singular. Do, Dost, Doth

Comment: "If thou dost not do battle with me this day, prithee, wilt thou do so on the morrow?"  In Elizabethan English, the former "dost" is present indicative, but the latter "wilt do" is future indicative.  "Wilt" is functioning as a helping verb, so "do" is the main verb (the infinitive without "to").  It's just like how you wouldn't say "will does."  Anyway, that's the difference.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason that we do not say "He will not does it". 'Will' (including the archaic second person form 'wilt') is followed by the base form of the verb ('do') not an inflectted present tense form ('does', 'doth', 'dost')